# Что именно показывает ссылка, вставленная в Google translate?

Tags: веб-программирование, seo, robots.txt, google-translate

Мой коллега - специалист по SEO, говорит, что ссылка, которая установлена в [переводчике Google](https://translate.google.ru/), может показать, как выглядит сайт для поискового робота. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Подскажите, насколько это правда?  Что именно показывает эта страница? Почему некоторые страницы отображаются ужасно, а другие нет?

Comment: Чтобы посмореть, как сайт выглядит для поискового робота нужно представиться сайту как поисковой робот с помощью заголовка User-Agent

Comment: Да, спасибо, про это слышал. Правда ещё слышал, что браузеры договорились залочить доступ к изменению данного заголовка в целях безопасности. Вопрос всё таки, о том что же показывает браузер переходя по ссылке вставленной в текстовое поле переводчика ?

Comment: по ссылке открывается сайт, переведенный транслятором

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш коллега прав. Используется один и тот же клиент, какой делает кэш сайта (индексация сайта). Внешний вид важен больше для клиента, чем на СЕО. У Google есть параметры как должна выглядит страница, но требования больше к мобильным устройствам, чем десктопным устройствам. И то, требования такого рода: маленький шрифт, ширина контента больше экрана и маленький отступы (касается кликабельных мест).
Насчет внешнего вида, могу предположить следующее:

1. Добавление своих тегов(`<font>` и т.п) с своими стилями во время перевода. Например, если селектор задан напрямую к элементу он работать не будет;
2. Загрузка контента у Google быстрая, но и таймауд не большой. В отчетах у бота (Search Console) находил проблему о не доступности изображения. Хотя изображение статическое и стабильных хостинг. При повторном сканировании проблема исчезает. ЗЫ. Если у Вас русская версия консоли, будет в `Search Console` помечена как "неизвестная ошибка";
3. Бот какой сканирует фильтруется некоторые участки кода, какие на его мнение не интересны;
4. Переводчик перевыполняет свою работу и переводит то, что не должен переводить;
5. Может загружать не все компоненты

Если хотите узнать как Ваш сайт видит поисковик, тогда лучше:

1. В поиске напишите адрес вашей страницы;
2. Нажмите на стрелочку (возле ссылки справа)
3. В проявившем окне увидите "Сохраненная копия". Именно по копиям Google использует как базу для поиска).

В качестве инструментов(бесплатных) рекомендую `Google Search Console`, `Google Analytics`

Дополнение №1
[image: DropDown меню в гугле]

Comment: Не очень понял, за объяснения о том как поисковик видит сайт. Не могу понять о какой "стрелочке возле ссылки справа" идет речь? Это вообще в поисковую строку вводить надо ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991, добавил в ответ